# How to add elemnts on database with AUTO_INCREMENT key in sqlite with datacontroller on Tizen?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to add random text on database with AUTO_INCREMENT key with data controller but I am unable to successfully insert data with out a key/id. Heres the code on datacontroller that creates the database:

```
sql_command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vault (ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Text VARCHAR(12))"; //then sqlite3_exec this command.
```

and here how I'm inserting data. bundle needs to be key value pairs so following wont work but I do not want to provide key and want to use auto_increment or anything like that :

```
ret = data_control_sql_set_data_id(ad->provider_h, "Vault");
b = bundle_create();
bundle_add_str(b, "", "'test data for vault'"); // want to use something like this, getting error here,
 bundle_add_str(b, "'test data for vault'"); //syntax error, must use a key.
 data_control_sql_insert(ad->provider_h, b, &req_id); 
 bundle_free(b);
```

So how can I add data to a database table and access from it with `auto-increment key`?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change codes like below

```
ret = data_control_sql_set_data_id(ad->provider_h, "Vault");
    b = bundle_create();
    bundle_add_str(b, "Text", "'test data for vault'");
    data_control_sql_insert(ad->provider_h, b, &req_id); 
    bundle_free(b);
```

For further information about how to use the api, please refer to 'https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/app-management/data-control#working-with-sql-type-data-controls'

Comment: Please try it first. As you know, it is not necessary to insert the AUTO_INPREMENT key directly.